# Mapbox markers disappearing when too far away from map center

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I have a Mapbox map with markers (I also use MarkerCluster). I get these HTML markers in JavaScript to determine their position (from viewport, not their coordinates), so I can add some indicators of markers that are not in viewport. But I realized that when I'm too far away from a marker (when zooming or dragging the map for example), the markers just doesn't appear in the HTML! It seems it's the normal behaviour because I can see the same thing happening in the official examples.

So, here's the question: is there any way to prevent this behaviour and always have the markers in the HTML?

Here is the JavaScript: (I use mapbox.js and leaflet.markercluster)

```
var places = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "description": ">Test 1"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-1.6313898, 47.2005156]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Test 2"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [2.3279346, 48.8960698]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Test 3"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [2.7391394, 48.7238554]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Test 4"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [55.4933757, -20.9034031]
        }
    }]
};

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic3RlcmVvc3VwZXIiLCJhIjoiY2lyM2JnMDIwMDAxM2k0bWNndmUzeTFhbSJ9.UZ-XuPASxGVtYFSqdVyppg';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map', null, {minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 16, center: [46, 8], zoom: 5, scrollWheelZoom: false, maxBounds: [[-100.0,-100.0],[100.0,100.0]]});
L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/stereosuper/cir3bgtaz001wjcnntu6n2axw').addTo(map);

var markers = L.mapbox.featureLayer(places);
var icon = L.divIcon({ iconSize: [30, 30], popupAnchor: [0, -20] });
markers.eachLayer(function(l){ l.setIcon(icon); });

var clusterPlaces = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({
    iconCreateFunction: function(cluster){
        return new L.DivIcon({ iconSize: [30, 30], html: '<div class="marker-cluster"><span>'+cluster.getChildCount()+'</span></div>' });
    }
});
clusterPlaces.addLayer(markers).addTo(map);

map.on('moveend', function(e){
    var htmlMarkers = $('.leaflet-marker-icon'),
        xCenter = $(window).width()/2, yCenter = $(window).height()/2;

    if($('.map-indicator').length){
        $('.map-indicator').remove();
    }

    htmlMarkers.each(function(i){
        var thisMarker = $(this),
            thisCluster = thisMarker.find('span').length,
            thisMarkerHtml = thisCluster ? thisMarker.find('span').html() : 1;
        var top = thisMarker.offset().top, left = thisMarker.offset().left;
        var indicator = '<button class="map-indicator map-indicator-'+i+'"><span>'+thisMarkerHtml+'</span></button>';
        var newLeft, newTop, angle, distance;
        var mapHtml = $('#map');

        if(top + thisMarker.height() < 0){
            mapHtml.append(indicator)
            if(left > xCenter){
                distance = (left-xCenter) * (yCenter/(yCenter-top));
                angle = Math.atan(distance/yCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newLeft = xCenter + distance;
                if(newLeft > $(window).width() - 40) newLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
            }else{
                distance = (xCenter-left) * (yCenter/(yCenter-top));
                angle = - Math.atan(distance/yCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newLeft = xCenter - distance;
                if(newLeft < 40) newLeft = 40;
            }
            $('.map-indicator-'+i).css({'top': '10px', 'left':  newLeft + 'px', 'bottom': 'auto', 'right': 'auto', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)', 'transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'}).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom', 'left', 'right');
        }else if(top > $(window).height()){
            mapHtml.append(indicator)
            if(left > xCenter){
                distance = (left-xCenter) * (yCenter/(yCenter+(top-$(window).height())));
                angle = - Math.atan(distance/yCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newLeft = xCenter + distance;
                if(newLeft > $(window).width() - 40) newLeft = $(window).width() - 40;
            }else{
                distance = (xCenter-left) * (yCenter/(yCenter+(top-$(window).height())));
                angle = Math.atan(distance/yCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newLeft = xCenter - distance;
                if(newLeft < 40) newLeft = 40;
            }
            $('.map-indicator-'+i).css({'bottom': '10px', 'left':  newLeft + 'px', 'top': 'auto', 'right': 'auto', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)', 'transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'}).addClass('bottom').removeClass('top', 'left', 'right');
        }else if(left + thisMarker.width() < 0){
            mapHtml.append(indicator)
            if(top < yCenter){
                distance = (yCenter-top) * (xCenter/(xCenter-left));
                angle = Math.atan(distance/xCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newTop = yCenter - distance;
                if(newTop < 0) newTop = 0;
            }else{
                distance = (top-yCenter) * (xCenter/(xCenter-left));
                angle = - Math.atan(distance/xCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newTop = yCenter + distance;
                if(newTop > $(window).height()) newTop = $(window).height() - thisMarker.height();
            }
            $('.map-indicator-'+i).css({'top': newTop, 'left': '10px', 'bottom': 'auto', 'right': 'auto', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)', 'transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'}).addClass('left').removeClass('bottom', 'top', 'right');
        }else if(left > $(window).width()){
            mapHtml.append(indicator)
            if(top < yCenter){
                distance = (yCenter-top) * (xCenter/(xCenter+(left-$(window).width())));
                angle = - Math.atan(distance/xCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newTop = yCenter - distance;
                if(newTop < 0) newTop = 0;
            }else{
                distance = (top-yCenter) * (xCenter/(xCenter+(left-$(window).width())));
                angle = Math.atan(distance/xCenter)*180/Math.PI;
                newTop = yCenter + distance;
                if(newTop > $(window).height()) newTop = $(window).height() - thisMarker.height();
            }
            $('.map-indicator-'+i).css({'top': newTop, 'left': 'auto', 'bottom': 'auto', 'right': '10px', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)', 'transform': 'rotate('+angle+'deg)'}).addClass('right').removeClass('bottom', 'left', 'top');
        }

        $('.map-indicator-'+i).on('click', function(e){
            var coordinates = map.layerPointToLatLng(thisMarker.context._leaflet_pos);
            map.panTo(coordinates);
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guessed absolutely right, Leaflet.markercluster plugin removes by default markers and clusters which are far away from your view port.

You can use [`removeOutsideVisibleBounds`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#enabled-by-default-boolean-options) option when you create your Marker Cluster Group to disable this behaviour.

Note that at high zoom, this may slow down your browser performance, as you will have plenty markers on map, which is one of the things Leaflet.markercluster tries to avoid.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!